# How to use TPL's ActionBlock to write to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, io, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am building a pipeline in .Net TPL that goes through bunch of data transformation steps and ultimately need to write output to a file. I am thinking about using ActionBlock to write to a file. However, I am not sure whether this can run into any problems...e.g. Multiple threads trying to write to same file.

Do I need to worry about write contentions? I am wondering whether it is good idea to set ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism to a value higher than 1. Could that cause any problems?

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Which hardware are you writing to?

Comment: Writing to a regular hard disk.

Comment: Then parallalizing your writes wont improve performance..

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering whether it is good idea to set ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism to a value higher than 1. Could that cause any problems?

Yes, it certainly could, depending on what exactly you do. Most types in .Net are not thread-safe, which means you can't use the same object from multiple threads at the same time. That includes `System.IO` objects like `FileStream`.

On the other hand, if you leave `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 1, you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Does your answer mean that you think TPL dataflow is a good option for this task or is there a better alternative? And can you show how to do this?

Comment: @Littlegeek The task in the question was: write the results from a TPL Dataflow pipeline to a file. `ActionBlock<T>` is a decent solution for that. If your requirements are different, the solution might be different too.